# Caching of permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching

I'm building a rails app that is entirely using a remote API for everything. The remote API has user info, permissions, etc.

As my user permissions exist in the remote API, I'm wondering how I'll manage checking whether a user has access to a specific page, on a controller level.

Right now that would mean that I would need to ping the API on every controller action, or I can start using caching. But I have no idea of when the permissions change, so caching can create sync problems.

How do people normally handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app only uses the permissions in a read-only fashion, there is little downside in caching the permissions returned by the API for even a few minutes.

If your app also allows users to somehow change the permissions, just make sure you fetch the non-cached permissions then.

You should also always use a non-cached version of the permissions when the user accesses something with a higher sensitivity/security level (logging in, changing password or other profile related things).

Answer (score 0):

When I made similar system I only had sync user once per session (on login).

Also I can advise you to sync active users in background, say each 5 minutes (if it's crucial)